# How do I get my picture captions to be responsive?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive, caption

I am trying to get my captions to be responsive when I resize the screen width.  I am finding that one column of my pictures (the left) has a caption that sticks to it, but the second column's captions do not, and are positioned under the first column's unless I position them specifically (and then they are not responsive).  How do I get my captions to stick to their corresponding pictures, both when resizing, and otherwise?

I have made the position for the image relative and the figcaption absolute.  I have tried positioning the div that encapsulates the pic and captions, removed floats, etc.

```css
img {
  padding-top: 15px;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

#pic2 {
  background-color: #4aaaa5;
  ;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 297px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 15px 110px;
  color: white;
}

#pic1 {
  background-color: #4aaaa5;
  ;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 297px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 15px 135px;
  color: white;
}

#pic3 {
  background-color: #4aaaa5;
  ;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 463px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 15px 133px;
  color: white;
}

#pic4 {
  background-color: #4aaaa5;
  ;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 463px;
  left: 534px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 15px 120px;
  color: white;
}

#pic5 {
  background-color: #4aaaa5;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 627px;
  padding: 15px 137.5px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1 class="header1">Portfolio</h1>
    <div class="wrapper2">

      <fig>
        <div class="gallery1">
          <img id="Pic1" src="./assets/images/download.jpg" height="150px" width="33.3%">
          <figcaption id="pic1">Island</figcaption>
      </fig>

      <fig>
        <div class="gallery2">
          <img id="Pic2" src="./assets/images/d2.jpg" height="150px" width="33.3%">
          <figcaption id="pic2">Track & Field</figcaption>
        </div>
      </fig>

      <fig>
        <div class="gallery3">
          <img id="Pic3" src="./assets/images/d3.jpg" height="150px" width="33.3%">
          <figcaption id="pic3">Bambi</figcaption>
        </div>
      </fig>

      <fig>
        <div class="gallery4">
          <img id="Pic4" src="./assets/images/d4.jpg" height="150px" width="33.3%">
          <figcaption id="pic4">City Scape</figcaption>
        </div>
      </fig>

      <fig>
        <div class="gallery5">
          <img id="Pic5" src="./assets/images/d5.jpg" height="150px" width="33.3%">
          <figcaption id="pic5">"Art"</figcaption>
        </div>
      </fig>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, take some time to format your code properly. Moreover, your code has lots of errors, please try one of online code validators then post your code. Last but not least, note that you can use [stack snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="gallery1">
<fig>
<img id="picture1" src="./assets/images/download.jpg" height="150px" 
width="33.3%">
<figcaption id="pic1">Island</figcaption> 
</fig>
</div>
```

Correct coding ^^ Also on line "43" there is a extra `</div>` tag.

You might want to recode. I'm guessing this is a homework project.

I will help you with the `HTML`, but the `CSS` is up to you to figure out.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class="header1">Portfolio</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="gallery1">
   <fig>
    <img id="Pic1" src="./assets/images/download.jpg" height="150px" 
width="33.3%">
    <figcaption id="pic1">Island</figcaption> 
   </fig>
  </div>


  <div class="gallery2">
   <fig>
    <img id="Pic2" src="./assets/images/d2.jpg" height="150px" width="33.3%">
    <figcaption id="pic2">Track & Field</figcaption> 
   </fig>
  </div>


  <div class="gallery3">
   <fig>
    <img id="Pic3" src="./assets/images/d3.jpg" height="150px" width="33.3%">
    <figcaption id="pic3">Bambi</figcaption>
   </fig>
  </div>   



  <div class="gallery4">
   <fig>
    <img id="Pic4" src="./assets/images/d4.jpg" height="150px" width="33.3%">
    <figcaption id="pic4">City Scape</figcaption>    
   </fig>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery5">
   <fig>
    <img id="Pic5" src="./assets/images/d5.jpg" height="150px" width="33.3%">
     <figcaption id= "pic5">"Art"</figcaption> 
    </fig>
   </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        } 
        .header1 {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 60px;
        }
        ul {
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
        }
        ul li {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
            display: inline-block;
        }      
        ul li img {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }               
        #pic1, #pic2, #pic3, #pic4, #pic5 {
            background-color: #4aaaa5;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 15px 135px;
            color: white;
        }
        .gallery1,.gallery2,.gallery3,.gallery4,.gallery5, {
            width: 19%;
            float: left;
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 class="header1">Portfolio</h1>
        <div class="wrapper2">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="gallery1">
                        <img id="Pic1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg">
                        <figcaption id="pic1">Island</figcaption>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="gallery2">
                        <img id="Pic2" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg">
                        <figcaption id="pic2">Track & Field</figcaption>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="gallery3">
                        <img id="Pic3" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg">
                        <figcaption id="pic3">Bambi</figcaption>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="gallery4">
                        <img id="Pic4" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg">
                        <figcaption id="pic4">City Scape</figcaption>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="gallery5">
                        <img id="Pic5" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg">
                        <figcaption id="pic5">"Art"</figcaption>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```